# Tor Installation Issue

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, tor

I tried to launch the Tor browser. 
I saw a screen that stated tor out-of-date so I downloaded the latest version. 
To make a long story short, I tried to launch a direct connection and an error message came up: "Tor fail to establish a Tor Network Connection. Loading Network status failed (No Route to host)."

I then chose the custom option. I was asked two questions:

- Does Internet provider prevent me to connect to tor?  My answer: No
- Does this computer need to use a local proxy to access the internet?
     Answer No.

The result: "Tor failed to establish a tor Network connection loading
Network status failed (No Router to host)"

This computer is an HP laptop running Windows 8.1 (I use it from my home).

I also have another laptop (Intel Pentium) running Windows Vista...and my Tor browser is working perfectly with it.

My ISP Provider (for both system is Comcast/Xfinity). 
How can I get up-and-running with tor browser on my Windows 8.1 HP laptop? 
Please provide help in LAYMAN terms.

Comment: Have you ever check out [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) and load up the VM that's already configured with Tor using Firefox, etc. This takes away the pain of doing all the Tor configuration so it may be at least worth something to consider or test to see if that'd suffice for your need.

Comment: Delete all tor installation folders. Only extract the installer with 7zip in a folder and run the browser exe file from there.